# How to to load a Pandas Data frame to Redshfit Server using OBDC driver?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, connection-string

I am relatively new to Python programming. I have searched previously answered questions related to this thoroughly but couldn't find a good solution.

Problem: I am intending to use the ODBC driver installed in my system to connect to Red-shift database. All entities - (Servername, host, port, Username, and password) are configured in the DSN. I was successfully able to make a connection to the database and read the table using the following code:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=AWSDW')
Query = """select *
            from <table_name>
            limit 10"""
df2 = pd.read_sql(Query,conn)
```

But the problem is I can get to load this dataframe in Redshift. Below is the code that I am trying to run:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql+pyodbc://AWSDW')
df2.to_sql('Abhi_Testing_Python_2'
           ,engine
           ,schema='sandbox'
           ,index=False
           ,if_exists = 'replace')
```

I know there is something that need to be done in Connection string for create engine. But just don't know what?

I am open to using some other method as long as I don't have to hard code my username and password in the code.

Comment: Can you post the error? It is most likely would be related to driver

Comment: This is the error message:NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:postgresql.pyodbc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you can't use postgresql dialect with pyodbc driver.

https://www.codepowered.com/manuals/SQLAlchemy-0.6.9-doc/html/core/engines.html

So, I ended up not using the Amazon Driver which I installed. Used psycopg2 instead.

```
connection_string = 'postgresql+psycopg2://'+username+':'+password+'@'+HOST+':'+str(PORT)+'/'+DATABASE
    engine = create_engine(connection_string)
```

This works. Only drawback was I had to hard code the HOST name in my code.